# How can I post data to Dynamics 365 multi-select picklist?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I have 3 columns with data as follows from a file

```
FirstName       LastName        Notes

Tom         10001       Note 1
Bob         10002           11003 
Karen           10003       11004
Renee           10004       Note 3
```

I need to scan these and send to Dynamics 365 Contact entity using the new Multi-Select Picklist attributes.

I can see that for example in the following provided on MSDN:

```
            OptionSetValueCollection activities = new OptionSetValueCollection();
            activities.Add(new OptionSetValue(1)); //Swimming
            activities.Add(new OptionSetValue(9)); //Camping

            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact["firstname"] = "Wayne";
            contact["lastname"] = "Yarborough";
            contact["sample_outdooractivities"] = activities;
            _serviceProxy.Create(contact);
```

that this will update / create a contact.

But in my situation do I need to scan the table and construct a contact object for each line or can I create one object and send?
Also is `sample_outdooractivities` a field in the Dynamics 365 Contact entity?
In my case Note won't be so what will I need to put there?
Do I have to let the CRM know it is a multi-select picklist (as it is a virtual type in CRM)?
How can I do this using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, MultiSelect optionset is not a virtual field, it is physical datatype like below. [Read more](https://www.encorebusiness.com/blog/multi-select-option-sets-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement/)

[image]

> Also is "sample_outdooractivities" a field in the Dynamics 365 Contact entity?

Yes, `sample_outdooractivities` is one of its kind in Contact entity from [MSDN sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/multi-select-picklist). The above sample code is the exact way to use it. Make sure your field is of the same datatype, but the sample data is quite confusing, **LastName** is blank or some numbers?  **Notes** is a Multiselect picklist but having text sometimes & numbers sometimes?

> But in my situation do I need to scan the table and construct a contact object for each line or can I create one object and send?

Yes, you have to read the each line from file & iterate through them, set in a new Contact object to create.

Comment: Im a bit confused here. So if I extract data from a source that needs to go into a multipicklist option in crm then I would have to create an object as above ? If the datatype was something different then I guess I would have to create a different object , it all depends. Now if my data has numbers as in the case of Bicycling which is 1000000000, then I would use OptionSetValue and look it up to get the string representation ? Is that correct interpretation of things or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Mel right, but your sample data has both Note 1 and 11003, what’s that?

Comment: So "note 1" is the string and 11003 is the value of a note which may be "Please send emails" as the details